# Posting text with link to facebook wall using C# sdk

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using facebook api for posting to the facebook wall post.THe post is getting displayed in the wall but i am not able to show the link which redirects to the site when it is clicked.
I need to show both the post as well as the link which points the posted post.
Following is my code

```
string viewDetailsLink = context.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority).ToString();
        viewDetailsLink = viewDetailsLink + "/" + "Blog" + "/Index/" + "0/" + blogPost.Id;
        viewDetailsLink = "<a href='" + viewDetailsLink + "'/>" + "click here to open" +"</a>";
```

But the whole thing is displayed as string instead of `click here to open`.

How do i resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing text instead of a link because you're closing our anchor tag prematurely. Try this instead:

```
viewDetailsLink = "<a href='" + viewDetailsLink + "'>click here to open</a>";
```

Here is the issue with your code:

```
viewDetailsLink = "<a href='" + viewDetailsLink + "'/>" + "click here to open" +"</a>";
                          Shouldn't close tag here  ^   ^   No need to concat  ^
```

Your code, fixed and prettied up a bit:

```
string viewDetailsLink = context.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority).ToString();
viewDetailsLink = String.Format("{0}/Blog/Index/0/{1}", viewDetailsLink, blogPost.Id);
viewDetailsLink = String.Format("<a href='{0}'>click here to open</a>", viewDetailsLink);
```